# X Axis values in eCharts not moving fast enough

Tags: angular, echarts

I have a moving x Axis in eCharts. The values move from right to left. But the values on the x Axis are not moving fast enough and get stuck on the right side. Is there anything I can do about it?

Data comes from a subsink. I´m using Angular.

[my echarts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xglx.png)

I can´t slow down the flow, since it should be that fast. The values on the x Axis have to move faster somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing an issue with your eCharts chart where the values on the x-axis do not move fast enough to keep up with the data coming from a subscription (subsink). To address this issue and ensure that the x-axis values move smoothly with your data, you can try the following approaches:

**Please insert some code.**

But without knowing the code:

- Be sure, that animations is enabled
- Use data buffer like this:

```js
      const dataBuffer = [];
    dataBuffer.push(newData);
    if (dataBuffer.length > maxBufferSize) {
      dataBuffer.shift();
    }
    chart.setOption({
      xAxis: {
        data: dataBuffer.map(item => item.x)
    
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: dataBuffer.map(item => item.y)
        },
      ],
    });
```

- And update the data freq:

```js
   dataStream.pipe(throttleTime(500)).subscribe(newData => {
   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an animation problem I was facing. With setting the animation to false the problem was solved.

xAxis: {
animation: false
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).